# Post links broken after migration

Tags: permalinks, urls

I just moved my wordpress site from one server to another. Moved all the files, moved the database, reconnected everything and it (almost) works perfectly fine.

**Except for this:** *The links to the different posts are broken (I only get 404s), eventhough the individual posts exist in the wp_posts table in the db and seem just fine.* I think this might be related to a URL change, but I didn't change my domain, nor did I change any of the directories.

**For example:** *http://example.com/* loads fine and displays the correct content, but when I click the e.g. *background* link it trys to load *http://example.com/index.php/background/* which results in a 404, eventhough I can see and edit the page *background* in the admin area.

What did I do wrong here? On the old server it loaded and displayed the correct content just fine.

Comment: Try going to Settings > Permalinks and click save.

Comment: It's rather a problem with server rewrites (`.htaccess` in case of Apache)

Comment: Ok this all makes sense, but how do I find the default URL of my posts? Is it always just e.g. example.com/newpost or example.com/index.php/newpost by default? I tried publishing a new post/page and it said /index.com/testpost, but still it resulted in a 404. What‘s the default location (URL) of my posts from the db? If I don‘t know that, I can‘t rewrite it to the correct one. I am using nginx btw.